# C++ ostream operator<< "no definition" error (Mac build only)

Tags: c++, macos, ostream

I have some code that compiles on Linux, but fails to compile on my Mac.  I'm compiling with gcc-4.2.1.  The code in question is C++, and it looks like this:

```
void print(std::ostream& os) const { os << std::string(*this) << " "; }
```

The error is:

```
error: explicit instantiation of Œstd::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const
std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits
= std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]¹ but no
definition available
```

I know the code works, because it compiles fine on Linux.  I can't tell whether the Mac error is due to a missing library or perhaps a different compiler version.  I thought maybe I could fix it by overloading the << operator myself, but so far my attempts have not worked.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My initial guess would be that it's not linking the C++ standard library for some reason. What compiler are you using and what flags are you passing it?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought maybe I could fix it by overloading the << operator myself, but so far my attempts have not worked

Please don't do that. What you need is to fix the root problem: why is the overload of `operator <<` not visible?

Without some context it is hard to say exactly what the problem is, but my guess is that you are not including all the necessary headers explicitly.

Make sure that both these includes are present:

```
#include <string>
#include <ostream> // or <iostream> if you need both input and output
```

Perhaps the implementation of the Standard Library you are using when compiling on Linux imports the `<string>` header from the `<ostream>` header, or vice versa, so including only one of those two headers turns out to be sufficient.

However, this behavior is not mandated by the Standard, so you cannot rely on it. Always include all the necessary headers explicitly.

Comment: `#include <ostream>` is enough here

Comment: I'm including both string and iostream already. :(  I looked at the stream header, and it includes bits/basic_string.h, where this is operator is defined, but the error persists.

Comment: @DavidLobron: Then I'm afraid you need to provide more context

Comment: The compile command: g++ -g -m32 -Werror -Wall -O3 -I/Users/dlobron/fp_dev/common/include -I/usr/local/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -idirafter /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext   -I/Users/dlobron/fp_dev/mapUtils/. -I/Users/dlobron/fp_dev/common/include/. -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local/\" -DPROGFULLPATH=\"/usr/local/sbin/\"  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -c  -MMD -MF /Users/dlobron/fp_dev/mapUtils/ConfigReader.o.d -MT /Users/dlobron/fp_dev/mapUtils/ConfigReader.o /Users/dlobron/fp_dev/mapUtils/ConfigReader.cc -o /Users/dlobron/fp_dev/mapUtils/ConfigReader.o

Comment: @DavidLobron: I mean you need to provide some context about the program (source code). Try to prepare an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Thank you.  I wrote an SSCCE, but it compiles fine.  I will try to isolate why my original example won't compile.  I'm using a version of make that my company develops, and it might have some weird problem.  The strange thing is that it only happens on my Mac - others using the same code are fine.